# How to tell when Visual Studio Enterprise Expires?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Is there an easy way to determine when and on what day my Visual Studio Enterprise Trial will expire. I need to tell my manager. One would think it would be on the About Dialog. Do not see it. Nothing came back on google

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question would be more suitable in [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com)

Comment: Guess you could check the creation date on one of the VS (sub)folders, then add 30 or 90 days to that.

Comment: dxiv okay 5/29/2020 .... How do i know if i  add 30 or 90?

Comment: @MarkWardell See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-unlock-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) - it's 30 days by default, 90 days if you signed in.

Comment: @dxiv Cool post as answer and i will Mark as answered if you are on point system etc

Comment: @MarkWardell Glad it helped, +1 if you post it as a self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright Here is what you need to know:

1. Out of the box VS 2019 Enterprise trial is a 30 day product
2. It can be extended to 90 days by logging on to a normal MS Developer account

Instructions are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-unlock-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

I feel like I am stealing points from @dxiv but he gave em to me. Thanks MS